# How do I link my eth1 network card to my DNS?

Tags: networking

On my Linux machine how should I configure my eth1 network card to work with my ddclient DUC? It can't use a static ip address because my router doesn't support it, but all I can find is the configuration for static addresses?

I want the eth1 network card to be the public address and my eth0 to be my private one for a DNS. I don't currently have eth1 set up, but this is my config:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system 
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5). 

# The loopback network interface 
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 

# The primary network interface 
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp 
post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Comment: I have never heard of a router that doesn't support static IP addresses. What is it? Also, is Network Manager running here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the  */etc/resolv.conf*  file. In this we can configure our dns like this:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 192.168.0.2
```

In example above it mean ip of primary and secondary dns. Replace the ip of the example for those belongs to your dns provider

Comment: From the file: "#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN". The file to edit is either /etc/network/interfaces or something like /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolvconf

Comment: @Rinzwind The files under `/etc/resolvconf` exist for this reason.